# I'm having a error exec this query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, count

I'm having a problem when I execute this `$query` on blade. I have 4 counts, but only the `$projetores` and `$infra_hdmi` show the result. And that case, the `$infra_hdmi`, the other has value, but look like don't execute on page load.

The strange thing is if I change the order of the `$query`, e.g. put `$infra_vga` above `$infra_hdmi`, the count works correctly.

```
$unidade = Input::get('unidade_id');
$bloco = Input::get('bloco_id');

$query = Projetor::where('unidade_id', $unidade);

$query->where(function($query) use ($bloco) {
    if (Input::has('bloco_id')) {
       $query->where('bloco_id', $bloco);
    }
});

$projetores = $query->get();

$infra_hdmi = $query->where('infra', 'HDMI')->count();
$infra_vga = $query->where('infra', 'VGA')->count();

$suporte_universal = $query->where('modelo_suporte', "Universal")->count();
$suporte_outros = $query->where('modelo_suporte', "Outro")->count();
```

On blade, I'm showing like this
    {{$infra_hdmi}}
    {{$infra_vga}}
    ...

Comment: try one thing don't use $query do whole thing instead, i mean complete query

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: But I need let a option to filter only by unidade_id. There's another way to do that without this query filter?
Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because you're adding where clauses to the same `$query` object.

What you can do to get around this is [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the `$query` before you add the `where` clauses for the count:

```php
$unidade = Input::get('unidade_id');
$bloco = Input::get('bloco_id');

$query = Projetor::where('unidade_id', $unidade)
    ->when(Input::has('bloco_id'), function ($query) use ($bloco) {
        $query->where('bloco_id', $bloco);
    });

$projetores = $query->get();

$infra_hdmi = (clone $query)->where('infra', 'HDMI')->count();
$infra_vga = (clone $query)->where('infra', 'VGA')->count();
$suporte_universal = (clone $query)->where('modelo_suporte', "Universal")->count();
$suporte_outros = (clone $query)->where('modelo_suporte', "Outro")->count();
```

I have also used [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#conditional-clauses) in the above code. This can be used instead of `if` statements with the query builder.

Comment: @Gelbcke Glad I could help.